# Does PFS provide any rules for gaining access to variant Aasimar abilities/physical features?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society, aasimar

Aasimar have a list of variant abilities and physical features, for which you would normally roll percent dice. My understanding is that you don't roll for anything PFS. If that's the case, is it possible to gain access to any of these variants?

Comment: As an additional note, Aasimars are no longer a legal character choice either, unless you already had one that was level 2 prior to the removal of them from the campaign.

Comment: Aasimar boon is a thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the PFS Additional Resources page for *Blood of Angels*:

> **Other:** variant aasimar abilities are not legal for Pathfinder Society;

The variant abilities you mentioned are not legal. The **heritages** (which replace the aasimar stat bonuses and some racial abilities) are legal, but the variants that normally require a percentile roll are not.